# Hiding previously displayed array elements

Tags: java, arrays, string, processing

So, I have an array of Strings that I have display to the screen one at a time through the `text()` function. But when I add to the index the previous array element stays on-screen and I can't figure out how to remove it. I just want to scroll through the text on screen and essentially have the next array element replace it on the screen.

```
Dialog[] main = new Dialog[12];
int index;

void setup() {
  for (int index = 0; index < main.length; index++) {
    main[index] = new Dialog();
}

void draw() {
  for (int index = 0; index < main.length; index++) {
    main[index].readDialog();
  }
}

if (mousePressed) {
  index++:
}

String[] textScroll = new String[12];


class Dialog {
Dialog () {
   textScroll[0] = "Welcome to the game!";
   textScroll[1] = "Are you ready to play?";
   etc...
}
void readDialog() {
   text(textScroll[index], width/2, 100);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, edit your question and add a tag for the programming language you are using.

Comment: Now please format your code into something readable.

Comment: I have to use processing, so it gets displayed to a premade window when I use the text() function. But it doesn't replace the previous string on screen

Answer (score 1):

First off, your syntax is not valid. You're missing curly brackets, and you've got an `if` statement outside of a function, which is not valid. Please try to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with valid syntax instead of a disconnected snippet of code.

But to answer your general question, you can clear out old frames by calling the `background()` function. Compare this code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/processing.js/1.6.6/processing.js"></script>
<script type="application/processing">

void draw(){
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
}

</script>
<canvas> </canvas>
```

to this code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/processing.js/1.6.6/processing.js"></script>
<script type="application/processing">

void draw(){
  background(32);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
}

</script>
<canvas> </canvas>
```

The first code draws a circle wherever the mouse is, and it doesn't clear out old frames so you can see all of the previously drawn circles. The second code draws a circle wherever the mouse is, but it clears out old frames so you only see the most recently drawn circle.

You want to do something similar to clear out your old frames. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/background_.html).

Answer (score 0):

Either use `background();` with the color you want as the background color as argument. For example, `background(0,0,100);` is blue background. This will clear your screen at the beginning of each `draw()` loop. But if you don't want to clear everything from screen everytime your program loop through `draw()`, just use a `rect()` same color as your background and on top of your text so that it cover your privious text.